# Resourcespace DAM system - setting external storage as AWS S3

Tags: php, windows, amazon-web-services, storage, dam

I've been spending few days trying to figure out how to set aws s3 as external storage for [Resourcespace](https://www.resourcespace.com). and i've been getting more confused with the this app.

I'm using the opensource version and trying to customize it to my needs.

I've been through the web app's lengthy documentation but couldn't find anything about setting storage (like other web apps out there) However, I found a feature called [syncdir](https://www.resourcespace.com/knowledge-base/systemadmin/staticsync) where it sets an alternative external storage (for backup) but not as an external storage, as from the documentation, it doesent seem to have a direct method to specify storage/integrate s3 with it.

I've tried the following:

1. I've tried using aws [s3 integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html) and how to integrate to any php website, by changing storing directory of 'storagedir' and directory of 'syncdir' in config.default file (i added the require s3 autoload file and added aws keys in config file), but it's not working, site is still storing locally

Note: I've integrated aws s3 before with [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/) & [Codeigniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/) frameworks successfully.

2. I tried adding the require aws-autoload into the file where uploading functions is, and tried to look for the code responsible to upload, but code seems confusing to me where the upload functionality is (its not a php funtion where `$_FILES` receives your upload.
3. Changed place of require aws-autoload into include/general.php, but no luck.
4. Followed up with some forums on the matter like:

   - [using external storage](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resourcespace/NUqAvvpFUuQ)
   - [Amazon S3 integration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resourcespace/OSsWnNPL73g)

I'm assuming that using the config file (to store AWS credentials and storage set to s3 bucket url), i include the aws-autoload in general/upload file, and it would automatically understand where it should upload, but no error or bug is reporting to address it.

But most of what i found is related to the paid version of the DAM system where it seems to be already set up on amazon.

Please advise, Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Wamp on Winddows 10 PC btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this discussion out, it might help you : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resourcespace/JT833klfwjc

It look like it is still a work in progress, so you may see the WIP code,

You will find links to code in the mentioned link.

Comment: Interesting.. I actually came across it after long research, will try it out. Thanks.